# how to write a generic script without explicitly writing the database name when it is a mandatory parameter

Tags: sql-server, delphi, t-sql

I need to run a script like

```
EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel AdventureWorks, 100;
GO
```

Now I'd like to have a generic version that uses the database I am connected to, is it possible in T-SQL?

Something like this, but this doesn't work:

```
EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel DBNAME(), 100;
GO
```

It doesn't work of course because a string is returned, I'd like to have the database referece returned... Is it possible?

Note Of course I can do it from a client application and using a parameter, like (Delphi example)

```
EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel :CurrentDatabase, 100;
GO
```

and replace it at runtime, but I'd like to have T-SQL only code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the EXEC approach.

```
declare @x nvarchar(2000)
set @x = 'alter database [' + DB_NAME() + '] set compatibility_level = 100;'
exec (@x)
```

BOL 2008 declares that sp_dbcmptlevel is deprecated, and to use ALTER DATABASE instead. I don't know whether 2005 supports this or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot, a GREAT ANSWER FULL OF INFORMATION. It solved my problem and made me avoid the use of a deprecated feature.

Comment: Doesn't work on SQL2005. Just use the above EXEC approach with sp_dbcmptlevel instead.

Comment: Tried to use the above EXEC approach with sp_dbcmptlevel instead, and got: Stored procedure 'sys.sp_dbcmptlevel' can only be executed at the ad hoc level  :(

Comment: Hi @Greg Woods - have you tried (replace [at] with @ symbol):
declare [at]currentDbName sysname;
set [at]currentDbName = db_name();
exec sys.sp_dbcmptlevel [at]dbname = [at]currentDbName, [at]new_cmptlevel = 80;

Comment: Thanks for making me look at this again, I'd missed the 'exec'. Doh!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
DECLARE @dbname AS nvarchar(500)
set @dbname = db_name()
exec sp_dbcmptlevel @dbname, 100;
```

Your server must of'course support the compatibility level you try to set ..

You should also have a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178653.aspx

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work.  Incorrect syntax near 'sp_dbcmptlevel'.

Comment: My mistake, I'd missed out the 'exec' at the start of the line